# Get index of changed element

Tags: jquery, html, list

I have a custom list in HTML wich I add rows dynamically when click in a button, the row has 2 column where the second column will be filled depending of the selection of the first column on the same row.

I allow to the user to choose the value of this new row from a list of possible values, after the user select the value I fill a second column on the same row with the possible values depending of the previous selection, but my problem is when I load with jQuery the values of the second column to show it if I have more than one row, the values are added always to the first one row.

So if I have more than 1 row and the user change the first column from the 3st row the jQuery will change the value of the second column on the 1st row...

All custom rows of the list has the same id and names... there are a copy of the first one when I add new one.

Is there any way to detect on onChange the index of the element which called the event?

I hope I explained it well.

Thanks so much.

Comment: _All custom rows of the list has the same id and names_ You should not use duplicate `ID`.

Comment: Ok, So I should add in the id an auto-increment number for example? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as the IDs are unique.